# Why string.replace(/./gm,function(s){...} can not remove newline in multiline string with `backticks` in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, backticks, multilinestring

**plese run the full functional  code snippet**.

```
function nlin(x){ 


// I have to use:  return x.replace(/[\s\S]/gm, function(e) {
return x.replace(/./gm, function(e) {
    /*
    
      the new var e is never 10==e.charCodeAt(0) !
      
      ** THAT is PROBLEM and ANSWER **
      
      @ VLAZ EDIT: I was too tired and didn't recognize @ VLAZ's answer:
      "The . character doesn't match any newline characters"
      regex /./ change to  "use [\s\S] (any whitespace or non-whitespace)
      to match everything"  
      would be elegant
      // I have to use:  return x.replace(/[\s\S]/gm, function(e) {       
      but I wrote additional code..
      
    
    */
    // the new var e contains one char after one , like while  , 
    // but I do not have to find out the count/size of var x
    // I could also use "x" instead of "e", it works exactly the same way ,
    // the value of x is available in the new variable e, 
    // in the function brackets function(e), 
    // so far I have not found any explanation for this javascript behavior.
    // You can often find it in jQuery:
    // line:
    // 1:   jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license   
    // 25:  }if(t.nodeType){return v.grep(e,function(e,r){return e===t===n;
    // 27:  }if(typeof t=="string"){var r=v.grep(e,function(e){return e.nodeType===1;
    // 
    console.log('in f(e): e.0  '+e.charCodeAt(0) +'  '+e[0] );
    console.log('in f(e): e.1  '+e.charCodeAt(1) +'  '+e[1]  );
    if( inside_e ){ e=e.replace(/\n/, ''); console.log('   [in]');} 

    return e;   
});};
```

Why string.replace(/./gm,function(e){...} can not remove newline in multiline string with `backticks` inside  inside " return x.replace(/./gm, function(e)  " but outside can.

...
I edited and have the answer...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div>Why string.replace(/./gm,function(s){...} can not remove newline in multiline string with `backticks` , but can remove other char</div><pre>
<div>with_newline--<span id="out"></span>--</div><div>
<button onclick="out_func()">replace outside function(e){}</button></div><div>
<button onclick="in_func()"> in function(e){replace} </button></div>
<div>newline_removed?----<span id="out2"></span>--</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x, outside_e=0, inside_e=0; 
function nlin(x){ 
    if( outside_e ){ x=x.replace(/\n/, ''); console.log('   [out]');}       
    console.log('outside f(e): x.0  '+x.charCodeAt(0) +'  '+x[0]+'( 10 is NewLine)' );
    console.log('outside f(e): x.1  '+x.charCodeAt(1) +'  '+x[1]  );
      
    // I have to use:  return x.replace(/[\s\S]/gm, function(e) {
    return x.replace(/./gm, function(e) {
        /*
        
          the new var e is never 10==e.charCodeAt(0) !
          
          ** THAT is PROBLEM and ANSWER **
          
          @ VLAZ EDIT: I was too tired and didn't recognize @ VLAZ's answer:
          "The . character doesn't match any newline characters"
          regex /./ change to  "use [\s\S] (any whitespace or non-whitespace)
      to match everything"  
          would be elegant
        // I have to use:  return x.replace(/[\s\S]/gm, function(e){          
          but I wrote additional code..
          
        
        */
        // the new var e contains one char after one , like while  , 
        // but I do not have to find out the count/size of var x
        // I could also use "x" instead of "e", it works exactly the same way ,
        // the value of x is available in the new variable e, 
        // in the function brackets function(e), 
        // so far I have not found any explanation for this javascript behavior.
        // You can often find it in jQuery:
        // line:
        // 1:   jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license   
        // 25:  }if(t.nodeType){return v.grep(e,function(e,r){return e===t===n;
        // 27:  }if(typeof t=="string"){var r=v.grep(e,function(e){return e.nodeType===1;
        // 
        console.log('in f(e): e.0  '+e.charCodeAt(0) +'  '+e[0] );
        console.log('in f(e): e.1  '+e.charCodeAt(1) +'  '+e[1]  );
        if( inside_e ){ e=e.replace(/\n/, ''); console.log('   [in]');} 

        return e;   
    });

};
function in_func(){ inside_e=1; outside_e=0; run(); }
function out_func(){ outside_e=1;inside_e=0; run(); }
function run(){
    // x multi_line_string_in_backticks_with_newline
    x=`
y`;     
            
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = x;

    x=nlin(x)   ;
    
    document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = x;
    console.log(' ');console.log(' ');                  
}
run( 0 );
</script></pre></body></html>
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) -> _"Inline Code"_

Comment: This question is a bit of a mess. Please consider looking over your code samples for undefined/undeclared variables (in the first example, what is `s`?). `if(0) ...` is a no-op. Is this what you intended?

Comment: (in the first example, what is s?) -- it is only to clarify , how the function looks like. .please see run code snippet - full functional.

Comment: The `.` character doesn't match any newline characters by default. That has always been the case, only newer standards added the `s` flag which allows `.` to match newlines. You can also use `[\s\S]` (any whitespace or non-whitespace) to match *everything*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the complete **code snippet** and show with two Buttn the code line that works - vs. the old position that Not work.

@ VLAZ
EDIT:
I was too tired and didn't recognize @ VLAZ's answer

regex /./ change to
" use [\s\S] (any whitespace or non-whitespace) to match everything "
would be elegant; I wrote additional code

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.